# Dualizable object that is not discrete

Tags: condensed-mathematics

In Example 9.6 of [Clausen-Scholze's Condensed Mathematics and Complex Geometry](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/scholze/Complex.pdf), they give an example of a dualizable object that is not discrete. In the process of doing so, they define $V_0:= \mathcal{M}_{< p}(\beta \mathbb{N})\otimes \mathbb{C}[T]$ and an endomorphism $f: V_0\to V_0$ given by diagonal multiplication by $(T, \frac{T}{2}, \frac{T}{3}, \ldots)$.

My question is, what exactly is this map? Is there an identification here of $\mathcal{M}_{< p}(\beta \mathbb{N})$ with an equivalent $p$-liquid vector space? I am mainly unsure why such a diagonal map should be countably indexed.

Comment: You could replace $\mathcal M_{<p}(\beta\mathbb N)$ by $\mathcal M_{<p}(\mathbb N)$ I think, essentially by Lem 4.5 & 4.6.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I believe $\beta\mathbb{N}$ is different than $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$, so it's not clear to me why it's possible to replace $\mathcal{M}_{< p}(\beta \mathbb{N})$ by $\mathcal{M}_{< p}(\mathbb{N})$, unless I am missing something. For example, I believe $\mathcal{M}_{< p}( \mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\})$ will fail to be compact projective

Comment: My point was not that they are the same, but different in a controllable way (i.e. modulo the boundary, precisely what these lemmas tell you). Note also that there is a lemma in this section which tells you that general trace-class maps factor through a map between sequential spaces. On the other hand, what you really need is the compactness — projectivity does not matter.

Comment: Okay, I'll think about this. Thanks a lot for your help.